# How do you block shared memory access until it is ready?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ipc

I'm trying to share a mutex between several processes. Each process will begin running at some random time so I need each to to be capable of setting up the shared memory and getting the mutex ready for usage. This works great so far:

```
int fd = shm_open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR);
if (fd < 0) {
    fd = shm_open(name, O_RDWR, S_IRUSR);
} else {
    //**critical section**

    // set up the mutex inside the shared memory
    // update permissions so other processes can access the shared memory
    fchmod(fd, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)

    //**critical section**
}

// mmap() shared memory
// pthread_mutex_lock()
// some other critical section
// pthread mutex unlock()
```

but if I add a sleep() right at the start of the else block to simulate slow creation of the shared memory I run into a problem where another process will see the created file and try to use it right away, before it's ready.

Is there any way to block the shm_open() call until the shared memory is ready? like telling it to wait until it has sufficient permissions to open the file (the last step of my critical section). Or is there some way to lock the file immediately on creation so that other processes must wait for it to be set up and unlocked, flock()?

Comment: Did you make the mutex `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED`? [`pthread_mutexattr_setpshared`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.html)

Comment: Why don't you use c++ threads, mutexes, and shared_mutexes?

Comment: @CaptainHatteras The processes may be totally different programs that accesses the same external resource. Not everything is solved best with threading.

Comment: @CaptainHatteras none of those can be shared across process boundaries, so you have to resort to platform APIs instead

Comment: as others have commented, I need it to be shared between different processes. @TedLyngmo yes I do use that, but the problem I'm encountering is if setting up the mutex is slow, I need to ensure other processes do NOT use it before it's ready

Comment: One approach is to have a separate [semaphore](https://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview) that controls access to the shared memory segment; modify the other programs so that, after opening the segment, they acquire the semaphore before accessing it.  Then, for the process that will create the segment, have it acquire the semaphore *before* creating it, and release it when initialization is finished.

Comment: Does your system support process shared mutexes?   Not all do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually solved my own question here, anyone have any suggestions for improvements?

Solution:

```
int lock_fd shm_open(setup_control, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR, S_IWUSR);
flock(lock_fd, LOCK_EX);

int fd = shm_open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR, S_IWUSR);
if (fd < 0) {
    fd = shm_open(name, O_RDWR, S_IRUSR);
} else {
    //**critical section**

    // set up the mutex inside the shared memory

    //**critical section**
}
flock(lock_fd, LOCK_UN);

// mmap() shared memory
// pthread_mutex_lock()
// some other critical section
// pthread mutex unlock()
```

Basically the locking file ensures that only 1 process can be acquiring or setting up the mutex at once which means by the time [the next] process is opening the mutex file it has already completed setting up

Comment: Is there a race-condition between the `int fd` line and the `critical section` line?  (i.e. some other process could run between those two lines and do the `shm_open(name, O_RDWR, S_IRSUR)` thing and then start trying to use the still-uninitialized shared memory, before the critical section was entered)

Comment: that's what the flock() on lock_fd protects against. no other process can enter that area until it has been unlocked

Comment: mark yourself as the answerer...

Comment: @JesseTaube it won't let me do it for 2 days